# Como obtener un valor de un diccionario a través de la lectura de un valor introducido por el usuario

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo este diccionario y quiero que cuando el usuario introduzca un valor de el automáticamente se busque la clave de ese valor y se imprima en pantalla.
diccionario={"rojo":"red","verde":"green","azul":"blue","blanco":"white","negro":"black","naranja":"orange","amarillo":"yellow","morado":"purple"}

Comment: Publica el código que tienes escrito hasta el momento y cuentanos cual es la dificultad que te detiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
diccionario={"rojo":"red",
             "verde":"green",
             "azul":"blue",
             "blanco":"white",
             "negro":"black",
             "naranja":"orange",
             "amarillo":"yellow",
             "morado":"purple"
}

#Recogida de valor por teclado
palabra = input( "Dime un color para saber su traducción: " )

if palabra in diccionario:
  print("Su traducción es: ",diccionario[palabra])
else:
  print('Este color no esta disponible :(')
```